# Trying to use multiple functions in sequence(Python)

Tags: python, function, oop

I've got this simulation project : I have several functions where I need them to work in a sequential mode. Every one of them contains multiple while loops and if, elifs, and conditions. When a certain condition is met, I want the function to stop and go to the other function. Here's the thing, there is a counter for the number of itterations, how can I start the next function counter from where function one stopped counting and exited? Another question , how can I combine all these functions in one big function so that I do not need to write the functions over and over everytime I want to simulate.
Thank you

I tried puting the fun2 as a return in func1 , so that when fucn1 reaches a certain condition it can start with func2. I don't know if its the right approach or thinking.

Comment: You will need to show some of your code, it's hard to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: A code example would be nice, as @AKX suggested.
As I understood, you are trying to give information regarding the func1 finish state to func2. For that, you can just pass an argument to func2 to inform it about func1 state when it called func2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.